# How to create SQL Function that fill the field with increment

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of `tickets` with a columns called `ticket_number` and `date`, which holds the date of creation.

The data in that table :

```
ticket_number   |   date 
150910.001          2015/09/10 
150910.002          2015/09/10 
150911.001          2015/09/11 
150911.002          2015/09/11 
150911.003          2015/09/11
```

I want to make a SQL function that create `ticket_number` based on the date. If the date of day is different, the last 3 digit reset to 001 again.

I am having trouble writing a SQL query to return such information.

So far,I have already tried :

```
    CREATE FUNCTION FcNoTicket(@date as datetime)
    RETURNS CHAR(10)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @newNumber char(10),@date_k char(7), @ticketNo as int
        SELECT @date_k =    RIGHT(Year(@date),2)+RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),DATEPART(MONTH,@date)),2)
    +RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),DATEPART(day,@date)),2)+'.' from tickets
        SELECT @ticketNo=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY @date ORDER BY @date)
    from ticket
        SET @newNumber=@date_k+right('00'+cast(@ticketNo+1 as varchar(3)),3)
    RETURN @newNumber
END
```

That code return continuous increment.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Better generating this in a single go than calling  function multiple times.

Comment: can you make the example query? Thanks for suggesting :)

Comment: so the `ticket_number` field is empty when you start?

Comment: yep, it depend on the date. So i have Stored procedure to fill the date first. Then i call the function to get the ticket_number

Comment: You are taking all the tickets from table in sequence. You need to put `... from transaksi where date = @date` in there.

Comment: i tried that on @ticketNo but it return null. Am i wrong on something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this:

- all tickes in a single query. Just add a `Create table AS`

[**SqlFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db40e/7)

```
WITH tickets as (
    SELECT [date], 
           row_number() over( partition by [date] order by [date]) as rn
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT [date],  RIGHT(Year([date]),2)
              + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),DATEPART(MONTH,[date])),2)
              + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),DATEPART(DAY  ,[date])),2)
              + '.'
              + RIGHT('000'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(3), rn), 3) as ticket_id
FROM tickets
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|                        date |  ticket_id |
|-----------------------------|------------|
| September, 10 2015 00:00:00 | 150910.001 |
| September, 10 2015 00:00:00 | 150910.002 |
| September, 11 2015 00:00:00 | 150911.001 |
| September, 11 2015 00:00:00 | 150911.002 |
| September, 11 2015 00:00:00 | 150911.003 |
```

Comment: Wow, thats great. But, i need that output from a function. This case is one of the question that given from my lecture.

Comment: Check [**HERE**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214485(v=sql.80).aspx) how create a function returning a table

Comment: You didnt accept any answer yet. Do you still have issue with this?

Answer (score 0):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7019af/2)

```
SELECT Replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR, ydate, 11), '/', '') 
       + '.' 
       + RIGHT('000'+Cast(Row_number() OVER(partition BY ydate 
                                            ORDER BY ydate)
                          AS VARCHAR(10)), 3) RN, 
       ydate 
FROM   yourtable
```

Comment: This Query return :

Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Type DATE is not a defined system type.

Comment: @FregyDamara : please check the SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    ticket_number VARCHAR(20)
    ,ticketdate DATE
    )

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES ('150910.001','2015/09/10'),('150910.002','2015/09/10')
    ,('150911.001','2015/09/11'),('150911.002','2015/09/11')
    ,('150911.003','2015/09/11')

--select * from @t
DECLARE @ParameterDate DATETIME = '2015/10/11' -- input of UDF
DECLARE @ticket INT
DECLARE @i INT = 3 --how many zero to replicate

SELECT @ticket = max(SUBSTRING(ticket_number, CHARINDEX('.', ticket_number) + 1, len(ticket_number) 
- CHARINDEX('.', ticket_number)))
FROM @t
WHERE ticketdate = @ParameterDate

SET @ticket = isnull(@ticket, 0) + 1

--return this result from function
SELECT stuff(convert(VARCHAR(8), @ParameterDate, 112), 1, 2, '') + replicate('0', @i
 - len(@ticket)) + cast(@ticket AS VARCHAR)
```